# Extract JMeter listener execution report using programming

Tags: jmeter, java-me, jmeter-plugins

Using JMeter Gui, If we choose aggregate listener and provide JMeter execution result file. it loads all aggregate results on JMeter table and that can be stored in csv file too.

I want this activity without loading to JMeter table and directly store to csv file using java code for summary, aggregate result, synthesis listeners.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in non-GUI command-line unattended mode using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd)

Example command:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv aggregate.csv --input-jtl your-test-result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

If you're still looking for a "java code" to copy paste from - the tool is [open source](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/tree/master/tools/cmd)